# Access to the scope from a directive template's function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, scope

I am trying to generate automatically some style stuffs (when loading the page, and after different API calls), so I created a directive used within the `<head>` markup in my view. The directive uses function to generate automatically the template, nevertheless I need to be able to use some simple conditions to add or not some stuffs into my style (if the value is not null). Without this condition need I was able to make it work without any problem without using the $compile but using only the "return { template: generate_dynamic_style ...}". But I was not able to evaluate the scope variables values within this generate_dynamic_style.

I tried passing the scope variables to it with compile. So here is my code :

```
    app.directive("dynamicstyle", function($compile) {
        var generate_dynamic_style = function(scope) {
            console.log('why scope works and I can see design Object inside :');
            console.log(scope);
            console.log('but scope.design doesnt work !!???');
            console.log(scope.design);
            var html_result = '<style type="text/css">'; // start style
            if (scope.design.layout_bg_image !== null) {
                html_result += 'html { color: {{design.layout_text_color}}; font-size: 12pt; text-align: {{design.layout_text_alignment}}; background: {{design.layout_bg_color}} url({{design.layout_bg_image}}) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; } ';
            }
            html_result += 'body { color: {{design.layout_text_color}}; font-size: 12pt; text-align: {{design.layout_text_alignment}}; } ';
            html_result += '</style>'; // end style
            return html_result;
        };
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // this log works
                console.log(scope);
                // this log doesn't work neither
                console.log(scope.design);
                var el = $compile(generate_dynamic_style(scope))(scope);
                element.replaceWith(el);
            }
        };
    });
```

Do you have any idea why I can get access to the scope (in Firefox JS console when I inspect element) and develop what is inside, I can correctly see the design object, and some other key-value pairs inside it. But for the second console.log(scope.design) I get a weird "undefined" ?
When I tried afterwards (as you can see in my example) the same things within the link, I'd got the same problem.
Do I use a wrong syntax to access to the content of the scope ?

I am really confused and losing time as I don't understand at all where the problem comes from.

I am open to other alternatives to fit with my needs : to be able to use conditions around the null value of scope variables within my template.

**Edit**: here is a plunker I've made: [Plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/qYrC7Lbhcs6CULFGB5VO/). Unfortunately I was not able to make my problem occur again because everything apparently works if I have everything in the same controller. Actually in my case I use routes. At least this plunker example allows us to get confirmation that my code has normally to work, I don't have syntax errors...

Thank you very much in advance for any type of help you should provide me.

Comment: Do you have a plunkr example?  scope.design is logged to the console within the link function too that might be confusing things.

Comment: Thanks I just created a plunker example that you can find in my edited question. I also changed a little bit my code in order to explain why I tried logging to the console from both places. BTW it works for both in the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding you properly.  It seems to work for me, I got the undefined message and put the directive so that its within the main controller.  If I understand correctly then this seems to be working as you expect it, [see my plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fJs994A5XBZUv2BszKlW?p=preview).

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <dynamicstyle></dynamicstyle>
   <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```